# AMPSCRIPT that shows today - 7

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can anyone advise how can I create an AMPSCRIPT that gives me today - 7?
I am basically want to issue each Sunday a graph that shows the stat a user had in the last  5 weeks.
so I need above each graph to show today (Sunday), last week (today - 7), two weeks ago (today - 14) and so on.
Can anyone advise?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
Today: %%=formatDate(now(1),"YYYY-MM-DD")=%%
Today - 7: %%=formatDate(dateadd(now(1),-7,"D"),"YYYY-MM-DD")=%%
Today - 14: %%=formatDate(dateadd(now(1),-14,"D"),"YYYY-MM-DD")=%%
```

**Reference:**

- [**dateAdd()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DateAdd.htm)
- [**formatDate()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm)